# How to delete Safari cookies from OS 10.7.2 terminal?

Tags: macos, cookies, safari

I would like to delete all Safari cookies from terminal on Mac OS 10.7.2.

I tried to delete `~/Library/Cookie/Cookies.binarycookies` (this is the only file in `~/Library/Cookie`), but it didn't help.

Please advise.

Comment: Maybe you should have asked this on: http://apple.stackexchange.com/, if you aren't trying to achieve it programmatically.

Comment: probably need kill the "cookied" process, before remove - your personal cookie-daemon... it is started from /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.cookied.plist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing part was to kill the `cookied` process:

```
killall cookied
```